# variable is not reassigned when changed in for loop js

Tags: javascript, html

when trying to change the variable value its not changing although it is **global**:

```
            let avg = 0
            let total = 0
            let courseNum = prompt("Enter the number of courses you have taken: ");
            let CourseInt = parseInt(courseNum);
            for (let index = 1; index <= CourseInt; index++) {
                const courses = prompt("Enter the grade for course #" + index + ':');
                for (let i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
                    if (parseInt(courses[i]) > 50) {
                        total =+ courses[i];
                    }
                    avg = total / courses.length;
                } 
            }
            prompt("YOUR AVG: " + avg)
        </script>
```

in the prompt popup it shows that the avg is **0**.

Comment: courses.length on an int?

Comment: You are indexing an integer not an array ...

Comment: @JaB im totally new to the language do i have to convert it to int? or do i have to remove the `parseInt` form the courses array?

Comment: it should be an array not a integer

Comment: @UmairFarooq but i want to store integers in the array? is that possible?

Comment: yes you can store numeric values in an array

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i edited the question can you recheck it please?

Comment: already said, but to make it clearer. the prompt for Enter the grade for course, returns a number, it was fine where parseInt was. the issue is in the loop you're doing `i < courses.length;` so if you entered 123, the value would be 3 because it has 3 characters, if you enter 9, it will be 1 but since 1 is greater then 0 your loop never runs, I wouldn't fix it, id just rewrite it https://playcode.io/964036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set an empty `array` `let total = [];` then prompting a user input for number of courses `courseNum`

then getting the grades inside the for loop & those grades are stored in the array `total` with `total.push(parseInt(courses));` meaning push the number that the user has inputted and store it in the array. after the user inputs all his grade like for e.g he has done three courses so the grade prompt will loop three times & in the end your array will look something like this"`[66,77,45]`
these are all the grade in one array.now i adding these three grades and dividing by the number of courses.
hope i could explain it.you can ask me anything in the comments...

```js
let avg = 0;
let sum = 0;
let total = [];
let courseNum = prompt("Enter the number of courses you have taken: ");
for (let i = 1; i <= courseNum; i++) {
  const courses = prompt("Enter the grade for course #" + i);
  total.push(parseInt(courses));
}
for (let j = 0; j < total.length; j++) {
  sum += total[j];
}
avg = sum / total.length
alert("YOUR AVG: " + avg)
```

Answer (score 1):

here :

```
let courseNum = prompt("Enter the number of courses you have taken: ");
let CourseInt = parseInt(courseNum);
```

Instead of changing the input value to `int` and store it in different variable, You can simply take the inputs as `Number` :

```
let courseNum = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of courses you have taken: "));
```

**Solution**

You need to store all the courses input in one array so that we can get all the numbers.And form that array we can get the total counts.

```js
let avg = 0
let total = 0
// we can store our inout numbers in arrayGrade array
let arrayGrade = [];
let courseNum = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of courses you have taken: "));

for (let index = 1; index <= courseNum; index++) {
    const courses = parseInt(prompt("Enter the grade for course #" + index + ':'));
    arrayGrade.push(courses); //appending all the courses input in arrayGrade   
    } 
    // console.log(arrayGrade)
    //get sum of all element in arrayGrade. You can console.log total and arrayGrade[i]
    for(let i in arrayGrade){
        total += arrayGrade[i];
        avg = total / arrayGrade.length
    }
prompt('avg is : '+ avg + "\n" + 'total grade is : ' + total)
```